# Python Socket Programming Clarification (Time)

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

Can someone clarify this code I found?

```
import socket
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

time_start = 0
time_end = 0
time_dict = {}
time_list = []

def upload_file(file_name):
    file_path = "client/" + file_name
    with open(file_path,'rb') as f: # open file for reading only in binary format
        while True:
            l = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE) # read in at most 1024 bytes at once from f
            while (l):
                s.send(l)
                time_list.append((time.time() - time_start)*(10**3))
                # checking condition
                if time_list[-1] == 0: # last element in time_list
                    a = 0
                else:
                    a = (len(time_list)*(BUFFER_SIZE)) // time_list[-1]
                if not time_dict.get(time_list[-1]):
                    time_dict[time_list[-1]] = a
                l = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
            # when there is no data
            if not l:
                f.close()
                time_list.append((time.time() - time_start)*10**3)
                duration_time = (time.time() - time_start)*10**3
                print('time:  start = ',time_start, ' end = ',time.time())
                print('time:  transfer_time = ', duration_time)
                print("file uploaded and graph is shown below!!")
                return time_dict
```

Should the time_start and time_end values be incremented somewhere? What is the time_list and time_dict doing in this code etc.? I know that 10**3 is 10^3 and // is floor division. 's' is the socket. What exactly is 's' being sent to?

Comment: This looks like an attempt to send a file through a socket while tracking how long it takes to send each part of the file. `s` is the socket used to send the data, and `time_list` and `time_dict` seem like an attempt at tracking how long it takes and the average data rate (but they won't work well because of the small amounts of time likely involved).